# Find the morphism of rings using morphism of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

I'm doing exercises in Hartshorne. I have a detail I want to ask.

Say $X$ is a scheme over $k$, which by definition means that there is a morphism of schemes $$(f,f^\sharp):(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\to (\text{Spec } k, \mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec } k} )$$Also given that $$(g,g^\sharp):(\text{Spec } k[x]/(x^2), \mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec } k[x]/(x^2)} )\to (X,\mathcal{O}_X)$$ is a $k$-morphism. Then $\text{Spec } k[x]$ must also be a scheme over $k$, right? Hence we must have a morphism
$$(\text{Spec } k[x]/(x^2), \mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec } k[x]/(x^2)} )\to (\text{Spec } k, \mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec }k } )$$
By the definition of a $k$-morphism, it's safe to choose such a morphism to be the composition of $(f,f^\sharp)$ and $(g,g^\sharp)$. Then this map induces a map on global sections $k\to k[x]/(x^2) $. My question is, can we explicitly describe this map?

It's just a mess when I tried to use the definition because the sheaves are not easy to describe.

Comment: without chasing through the definitions, it's got to be a $k$ algebra map and there is only one such map $1 \mapsto 1$.

Comment: (it's probably good to chase through the definitions anyway though)

Comment: I don't understand what your complaint is with the sheaves being hard to describe. Both $\operatorname{Spec} k$ and $\operatorname{Spec} k[x]/(x^2)$ are one-point spaces, with very simple structure sheaves.

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_{\Spec A}(U)$ is defined to be the set of all function $U\to \prod A_p$. I don't really understand this  set, so it's hard to understand the map

Comment: @KReiser yes I know the two rings here have only one maximal prime. But $O\SpecA(U)  $ is defined to be the set of all function $U\to \prod A_p$. So I know there is a ring morphism between the two sets, but I don't know what it maps each element to.

Comment: it should be easy, so I'm hoping someone can walk me through it. I just start to learn AG

Comment: If you're following Hartshorne, one of the *first things* he does in defining schemes is to explain what the global sections of the structure sheaf on an affine scheme are. You should read this.

Comment: yes it's proposition 2.2. II find the proof a bit abstract for me right now. So I'm hoping I can learn something from an example so that it's more natural.